Extended Kalman Filter initialization leads to no progress
I am currently trying to implement a modified version of an Extended Kalman Filter for LTE.
My source is this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257878036_Kalman_interpolation_filter_for_channel_estimation_of_LTE_downlink_in_high-mobility_environments), where the update and correction terms are given with formulas.
My Problem is, that my prediction never makes an update, because a specific term is always $0$.
The following will show what I understood so far:
At $k=0$ we received a pilot symbol and for the initialization of $A_0$ an identity matrix is suggested. The $h_0$ can be calculated by the least square estimation (eq. 25). With $a_0$ being the diagonal of $A_0$ we can use $z_0 = [a_0^T $ $ h_0^T]^T$ as a new state.
With Eq. 19 we can make our first prediction $\hat{z}_{1|0} = f(z_0) =  \begin{bmatrix}\hat{a}_0\\\hat{A}_0\hat{h}_0\end{bmatrix}$ .
So $\begin{bmatrix}\hat{a}_{1|0}\\\hat{h}_{1|0}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {1}\\\hat{h}_0\end{bmatrix}$ because $A_0$ is an identity matrix and $a_0$ only contains 1 for each entry.
For $k=1$ we receive $y_1$ and our prediction for $X_1$ was made as step 3 and 4 of the summary suggested: $X_1 = \hat{x}_1 = \frac{y_1}{\hat{h}_{1|0}}$ .
Now for the correction part of $\hat{z}$ we use eq. 23:
$\hat{z}_1 = \hat{z}_{1|0} + K_1(y_1-X_1\hat{h}_{1|0})$ .
But with $X_1 = \frac{y_1}{\hat{h}_{1|0}}$ we get $\hat{z}_1 = \hat{z}_{1|0} + K_1(y_1-\frac{y_1}{\hat{h}_{1|0}}\hat{h}_{1|0})$  resulting in $\hat{z}_1 = \hat{z}_{1|0} + K_1(y_1-y_1)$ .
This means $\hat{z}_1 = \hat{z}_{1|0}$ and since $\hat{z}_{1|0} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {1}\\\hat{h}_0\end{bmatrix}$ my $A_1$ still is an identity matrix and the channel frequency response for my sombol $k=1$ is the exact same as for $k=0$.
So like this neither my $A$ nor my $h$ will ever change and my kalman gain $K$ never has an impact on my correction. I am sure I misunderstood something or did a wrong assumption at some point, but I can't figure out where. I would really appreciate if someone could show me where my mistake is or show me something that could help me to better understand my problem.
Many Thanks in advance,
Leon

The value $y_1$ is the actual noisy measurement. The $X_1 \hat{h}$ term should be the predicted measurement as a function of your state, and usually should not depend on the actual measurement. Just glancing at the paper, my guess is that you are misunderstanding what the $X_1$ matrix is.

$X$ is the information I sent. For $X_0$ this information is known, since $X$ is a pilot symbol at $k=0$. Therefore I can compare my received signal $y_0$ with $x_0$. But for $k=1$ I do not know what the signal $x_1$ was, so I can only compare my noisy measurement $y_1$ with my predicted measurement $X_1\hat{h}_{1|0}$. But this predicted measurement gets calculated with the noisy measurement itself. That's what confuses me. (edited formatting)
